# How to construct non-leap datetime list in python?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

I have a user case that I need always the non-leap calendar whatever the year is a leap year or not. I want to construct a 6-hourly datetime list for year 2000, for example:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pa

tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
dt = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,)
ts = [dt+i*tdelta for i in range(1460)]
pa.DatetimeIndex(ts)
```

With this block of code, I get the result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 06:00:00',
               '2000-01-01 12:00:00', '2000-01-01 18:00:00',
               '2000-01-02 00:00:00', '2000-01-02 06:00:00',
               '2000-01-02 12:00:00', '2000-01-02 18:00:00',
               '2000-01-03 00:00:00', '2000-01-03 06:00:00', 
               ...
               '2000-12-28 12:00:00', '2000-12-28 18:00:00',
               '2000-12-29 00:00:00', '2000-12-29 06:00:00',
               '2000-12-29 12:00:00', '2000-12-29 18:00:00',
               '2000-12-30 00:00:00', '2000-12-30 06:00:00',
               '2000-12-30 12:00:00', '2000-12-30 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1460, freq=None, tz=None)
```

However I want the February to have 28 days and thus the last member of the output should be '2000-12-31 18:00:00', are there some way to do this with python? Thanks!!

Comment: I hope they don't want the day of the week for a given date in this odd arrangement. If not you could always use a non leap year that starts on the same week day as 2000.

Comment: how do you want to use the list later? What is the context? Even if you create the list with adjacent `2000-02-28 18:00:00`, `2000-03-01 00:00:00` entries; the difference is still more than 24 hours if you use `datetime64[ns]` data type. Most libraries working with dates in Python assume proleptic Gregorian calendar. You should probably avoid `datetime` type completely if you need non-Gregorian calendar otherwise you have to fight it at each step to get results desired in your case.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check for the `.month` and `.day` attribute for the datetime instance. So just insert a condition that checks:

1. `if month == 2`
2. `if day == 2`

If both the conditions are `true`, you don't add it to the list.

To make it more descriptive:

```
ts = []
for i in range(1460):
    x = dt + i * tdelta    
    if x.month == 2 and x.day == 29:
        continue

    ts.append(x)
```